# How to change path's width and height drawn by Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, svg, drawing, raphael, dimensions

I have path that I then draw with [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/). Code looks like this:

```
var paper = Raphael($('#draw_here')[0], '32', '32');

var star = paper.path("M 22.137,19.625 32,12 20,12 16,0 12,12 0,12 9.875,19.594 6,32 16.016,24.32 26.008,32 z");

star.attr({
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    title: 'This is a STAAAAAAAR!'
});
```

It works and it draws 32 x 32 pixels big star. **How to change it's width and height?**

I tried to do this:

```
var paper = Raphael($('#draw_here')[0], 64, 64);

var star = paper.path("M 22.137,19.625 32,12 20,12 16,0 12,12 0,12 9.875,19.594 6,32 16.016,24.32 26.008,32 z");

star.attr({
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    title: 'This is a STAAAAAAAR!',
    width: 64,
    height: 64
});
```

...but all that changes is “paper element's“ width and height, not star's.

The thing I want to do is put effect that star gets bigger when mouse's cursor is on it.

Thanks in any advice!

P.S. I didn't write the path myself, it's get from [Iconic set](https://github.com/somerandomdude/Iconic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to adjust the path too!
Just try it on the [Raphaël Playground](http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html).

The width and height attributes are just the size of the element to draw on, but the path coordinates are still the same.

**For a simple resize you may also use**

```
star.transform("s2");
```

to resize it to the `2x` as before.

**If don't want to edit the path and simple scale it**, you should use the `transform` method to resize it and `translate` the full path by a certain value.

```
star.transform("t32,32 s2");
```

This for example will move the object by `32px` from the top and `32px` from the left and resize it to the `2x` as before.

Comment: Thanks, this is simply awesome! ^^